# How to stop D3.js from blocking when returning to page

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

I currently have a web app that is using both native d3 charts and charts using the c3.js chart module.

My charts are updating every 1-2 seconds due to changing data and there are maybe 3-4 charts on the screen at any one time.

I've noticed that if I change tabs in chrome or minimize the window, when I return back to the tab, d3.js spends a LONG time in d3_timer_step completely locking up the UI for 5+ seconds (depending on how long the user is away from the tab), this can essentially lock up the UI for many minutes if the user is away for 30 mins or so.

I'm assuming what is happening is the d3 animations are queuing up while the window is blurred and then just hammering the UI thread when it is focused again.

Obviously I can (and probably will anyway) stop updating my charts when the window is not visible, however my question is around whether anyone else has found this issue and what their solution was? e.g. is there an option in d3 to limit the animation buffer or similar?

Comment: I would post this on the d3js Github project issues page (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues).  As far as I understood, the animations shouldn't be getting queued up like this since requestAnimationFrame should be inactive or drastically reduced.

Comment: @Bill, Thanks, the note about requestAnimationFrame sent me on the right path. It seems that because it is paused, the transitions are queueing up so when the focus is returned there is a huge backlog of transitions which causes the d3_timer_step to take a long time going through the backlog. A possible solution seems to be to use selection.interrupt to reduce the number of transitions. I have also raised an issue to see if there is something d3 can do internally to improve the experience. See: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/2211

Comment: Probably an issue with `c3`. Could you put up a fiddle that reproduces your problem?

Comment: Sure. This is a chart built using c3.js (It appears to be the culprit), Just leave the page open for about 2mins on an inactive tab then return to it.
http://jsfiddle.net/solgar/phLqwrmb/

Comment: Have you found solution @NickB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a C3 maintainer.

My guess is that you're using a really old version of C3 (0.4.9); 0.4.11 fixes this, I think there was a bug with `data.load`. Please try updating your versions!

Answer (score 2):

In my case 0.4.11 doesn't change anything (and even chart.destroy() don't do a thing surprisingly). The core issue is c3js continue to schedule d3 transitions even if blurred and destroyed in the moment. D3 on its side postpone all the transitions until the tab is focused and then BAM - perform every in a single blocking request.

If this is the case, you may change chart's global transition duration to `0` or `null`. Most of internal c3 functions rely on transition duration as a flag to perform transition or not (in case of 0).